# quality analysis of fitted pyramid

Tags: math, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

sorry for posting this in programing site, but there might be many programming people who are professional in geometry, 3d geometry... so allow this.

I have been given best fitted planes with the original point data. I want to model a pyramid for this data as the data represent a pyramid. My approach of this modeling is

> 1. Finding the intersection lines (e.g. AB, CD,..etc) for each pair of adjacent plane
> 2. Then, finding the pyramid top (T) by intersecting the previously found lines as these lines don’t pass through a single point
> 3. Intersecting the available side planes with a desired horizontal plane to get the basement
>
> In figure – black triangles are original best fitted triangles; red
>   and blue triangles are model triangles
>
> I want to show that the points are well fitted for the pyramid model
>   than that it fitted for the given best fitted planes. (Assume original
>   planes are updated as shown)

Actually step 2 is done using weighted least square process. Each intersection line is assigned with a weight. Weight is proportional to the angle between normal vectors of corresponding planes. in this step, I tried to find the point which is closest to all the intersection lines i.e. point T. according to the weights, line positions might change with respect to the influence of high weight line. That mean, original planes could change little bit. `So I want to show that these new positions of planes are well fitted for the original point data than original planes.`

Any idea to show this? I am thinking to use RMSE and show before and after RMSE. But again I think I should use weighted RMSE as all the planes refereeing to the point T are influenced so that I should cope this as a global case rather than looking individual planes….. But I can’t figure out a way to show this. Or maybe I should use some other measure…
So, I am confused and no idea to show this.. Please help me…

[image]

Comment: you would be better off removing the C++ tag and adding the math and geometry tags

Comment: Sorry but your question is quite cloudy. I've read it twice but was unable to even understand the initial process. Maybe you want to rework your question. A good start would be to take care of case sensitivity. Also some figures could be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to find out whether the second step made the fit better? Or do you want to compose an argument that the second step made the fit better, even if it really didn't?

Comment: @Beta: actually i think step 2 improves the quality of fitted plane. so i want to show that because of this step 2, i got a more enhanced model. In case of not getting a signle point, i thought this way would be better..so applied this way. now want to prove this is as so. No idea to do this. any help plz

Comment: @AD-530: ok thanks,... i changed my original post and put a figure too.. hope now it is clear. so please let me know a way to show this. thanks again

Comment: Take the square of the distance from a point to its plane. Sum over all points. The smaller the sum, the better the fit.

Comment: @Beta: i think you said how to compute square error. actually my problem is what is the meaningful way to show this that step 2 enhances the quality of planes.

Comment: Solve a simpler problem first: you have some points that belong on a plane. You have two candidate planes. How can you show that one is better than the other? If sum-of-squares doesn't convince you, then what can?

Comment: @Beta: ok..  if i refer your first response: do you think that step2 doesn't make any improvement?... now i am again thinking of that i am trying with wrong argument.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18499/discussion-between-beta-and-g-niro)

Comment: @Beta: any comments from ur side plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given the best-fit planes, why not intersect the three of them to get a single unambiguous `T`, *then* determine the lines `AT`, `BT`, and `CT`?

This is not a rhetorical question, by the way.  Your actual question seems to be for reassurance that your procedure yields "well-fitted" results, but you have not explained or described what kind of fit you're looking for!

Unfortunately, without this information, your question cannot be answered as asked.  If you describe your goals, we may be able to help you achieve them -- or, if you have not yet articulated them for yourself, that exercise may be enough to let you answer your own question...

---

That said, I will mention that the only difference between the planes you started with and the planes your procedure ends up with should be due to floating point error.  This is because, geometrically speaking, all three lines should intersect at the same point as the planes that generated them.

Comment: I think you missed the point. The three starting planes are not necessarily intersecting in one point. So it's not possible to just intersect them and get T.

Comment: @AD-530: any idea to prove this sir.. do you think my step2 enhances the original planes?

Comment: @comingstorm: originally planes are fitted using Hough tranform but small distance threshold is given when fitting the planes by Hough. yes, as AD-530 told lines are not passing one point. i am not sure that i got your point... actually i did least square fit...but i am thinking that step2 further enhances the fitting accuracy of orginal planes.. what do you think? how to prove this..

Comment: Unless the intersection lines happen to be exactly parallel, three 3D planes *always* intersect in exactly one point.  How do you figure that they dont?

Comment: Specifically: if your three planes are represented as `[a,b,c,d]` such that `ax+by+cz+d=0` describes the points on the plane, you have a system with three linear equations in three unknowns.  In general, you can solve such a system uniquely for `x`, `y`, and `z`, which gives you the intersection point.

Comment: @comingstorm: yes i agree. plane intersetction is the best way to get intersection point. as I used this line intersection method, i cannt got back. so, to this end, i should continue this..so i got the intersection point which is closest to all the lines using weighted least square way (plz look my post). accordingly i got new planes as all planes passing now point T. so I have 2 questions now: do you think this way enhance the quality of original fitted plane? i think to use RMSE to asses quality of plane fitting before and after T is this good way? plz comment me these 2 questions. thanks

Comment: As I said:  they should not change the fit significantly; there is no reason to compute new planes but even so there shouldn't be much difference.  The reason your lines don't intersect exactly is not because of the fit, but because of floating point errors in calculating them.  So, your least squares intersection point ends up as just a fancy symmetrical way of averaging out your floating point errors.

Comment: I do think that it would be a good idea to check the RMSE for some sample data.  If there is no significant difference, then this will help convince yourself of the above.  Also, if I am somehow wildly off-base, or if there is something wonky with your calculations, checking will indicate that, too 8^)

Comment: @comingstorm: thanks for the comments,,yes the differences are very small and smaller than 4th decimal place. but my effort is to convince that it works.. sometime it worse as it depends on the weights. but i think it is meaningful to show this as i like to say this in my report. would it be technically accept if i say this as a floating point error..

Comment: If the differences are very small and often for the worse, that is an indication that it *does not* work:  the procedure is statistically meaningless, you should not use it, and if I had to take a guess, you probably shouldn't even mention it in your report.  I realize you probably spent a lot of time and effort on it; just consider it as a learning experience.

Comment: @comingstorm: Not always worse. for few planes only. if i ask again... if i mention this as a floating point problem as u explain.. then is it technically accepted words or just only speaking way..?

Comment: I have very little information about your project, and none about the nature of your report.  Also, it seems like you are trying to use this question to justify some preordained conclusions of your own.  In either case, I'm afraid I really have nothing else of value to contribute.

Comment: @comingstorm: yes i understood your point. but, I am so poor in theoretical side.. so I want to know the reason or the way to mention this type of problem in technical way. considering a general case or imaginary case like this, then how to address this? as a floating point averaging problem or.. plz give some support to explain this,, i really need your comments. thanks